# Shouldn't this key be unique?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

Trying to make a simple application based in .NET Core with a React front-end and i'm struggling to figure out why my data is not displaying, I'm going off of the React template for .NET Core, and trying to display an array of items in a table and the chrome console keeps telling me my keys should be unique but I'm stumped as to why it's not unique.

Here's the React JavaScript:

```
    static renderPlantTable(Plants) {
    return (
        <table>
            <tbody>
                {Plants.map(plant =>
                    <tr key={plant.PlantID}>
                        <td><img src={"https://blog.ontariotechu.ca/hs-fs/hubfs/growth.gif?width=343&name=growth.gif"} alt=""></img></td>
                        <td>{plant.PlantName}</td>
                        <td>{plant.PlantID}</td>
                        <td>{plant.timelastWatered}</td>
                        <td><Button id="btnstart" onClick={this.StartWater}>Water me</Button></td>
                        <td><Button id="btnstop">Stop</Button></td>
                    </tr>
                   
                    
                    )}
            </tbody>
        </table>            
        
        );
}

render() {
    let contents = this.state.loading
        ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
        : Home.renderPlantTable(this.state.Plants);
    return (
        <div>
            {contents}
        </div>
        );
}


async PopulatePlantData() {
    const response = await fetch('Plant')
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ Plants: data, loading: false })
  
}
```

Here's the controller that the React fetches

```
   private static readonly string[] PlantNameArray = new []
    {
       "fern","ficus","daisy","sunflower","apple tree"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<PlantController> _logger;

    public PlantController(ILogger<PlantController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Plants> Get()
    {

        var rng = new Random();
        int plantid = 0;
        return Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(index => new Plants
        {
            TimeLastWatered = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            PlantName = PlantNameArray[rng.Next(PlantNameArray.Length)],
            PlantID = plantid++
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Can you try using (plant,i) in your map and use that 'i' as a key, just to see if that works, its not the ideal solution but i want to see if thats the real problem

Comment: When I add the i it throws an error on the page saying plant isn't defined, i'm probably adding it in the wrong spot : Plants.map(plant , i =>

Comment: yea you have to have parantheses ((plant,i) => {} )

Comment: That did in fact fix the error

Comment: Can you show the `Plants` class? There might be issue with the setter of `PlantID`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `int plantid` variable increases every time you call the `Get()`function? Try console.logging the `plantid` variable every time you call the `Get()` function and maybe you can figure out where is the bug.

Comment: It does increase actually, part of the reason why i'm so confused, thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Try making it a string instead of an int and adding it an extra letter every time the function Get() is called.